# howto encrypt passwords in configuration files, grails [and java]

Tags: configuration, encryption, grails

I am looking for a step-by-step how to on securing passwords put in configuration files, in grails.  This means securing passwords in Config.groovy and DataSource.groovy.  There are a lot of google results that contains bits and pieces of the answer, but no concise guides on how to do this.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thanx

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  These files aren't publicly accessible

Comment: I don't write the requirements.  Its just necessary.  I actually thought this was possible and somewhat standard practice -- I have seen encrypted strings in configuration xml files before in non-grails j2ee apps.  I am just trying to find a guide to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Config.groovy, you could always just encrypt the password some way and then put that hash in Config.groovy, manually.  When you need to use it in your code, have some code to decrypt it for you.  Doesn't seem that hard.

DataSource.groovy is a different animal, however, since it is fed into the Hibernate API for you.  I did see some code like this on the interwebs and it seems like it is headed in the right direction...

```
dataSource { 
   pooled = false 
   driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" 
   username = "sa" 
   password =  someEncryptionApiObject.decrypt(propertyFile.readProperty("MyPassword")) 
}
```

...where you would encrypt the property file containing the data you need, and decrypt when needed.

Comment: yes, this solution seems very similar to this

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3620

it seems the hibernate data source has machinery in it to decrypt given a codec.  Im wondering about other passwords though; we also use the mail plugin which requires its own password.  I think your advice to just decrypt inline, since .groovy files are code, is good.  Ill try later today/tomorrow.

Comment: What are the advantages here compared to storing the password as plain text on the file system but with restricted access?  It seems like you will need to store something on the filesystem, either private key or the password itself.  Ultimately wouldn't you have about the same vulnerabilities in both approaches?  Maybe the encrypted password on the filesystem buys you some additional security through obscurity?

Comment: A copy of DataSource.groovy might be available on the laptops of the developers and on a repository server (eg. github). All of these might get hacked or stolen. A single file on the production server can be more easily protected than the developers' laptops and the repository server. But indeed, that single file on the procuction server is still the weakest link.

Comment: New GRAILS-3620 link: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/4063

Answer (score 1):

The question is: against what do you want to protect your config file? One possiblity would be to use file system encryption. Another one would be to encrypt the file with a strong password and ask for the password, when the applications starts. But consider that the application can not be restarted then without entering again the password!

Take a look at the [Apache httpd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslpassphrasedialog) to see how Apache handles the same problem.

Answer (score -4):

*Config.groovy* and *DataSource.groovy* is not a configuration file, it's a configuration class. Compiled results are direct not readable.

### Update

The use a obfuscation tool on your config classes.
Here is [a list](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/431511.html).

Comment: byte code is not secure in this way. Strings can often be read directly in byte code files.

Comment: What deamon said, plus anyone who has access to your Config/DataSource.groovy files has access to your credentials.