# How to use encrypted configuration data in Grails application?

Tags: grails

I am working on a Grails based application.
I have configured my application to work with  mail and Database setting from 
configuration file(app-config.properties file present in the conf folder).
It is working properly.

### **Config.groovy**:

```
grails<br /> 
{<br />
    mail<br />
    {<br />
        host = ""<br />
        username = ""<br />
        password = ""<br />
        port =  0<br />
        from =  "" <br />
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true" ]<br />
    }<br />
}<br />
**app-config.properties**:<br />
```

---

```
grails.mail.default.from =abc@test.com<br />
grails.mail.host =mail.test.com<br />
grails.mail.username =testUser<br />
grails.mail.password =testPassword<br />
grails.mail.port =25<br />
grails.mail.from = abc@test.com<br />
```

**Some Other Details**:
1. Grails Version : 1.3.7
2. Mail Plugin version : 1.0

My requirement is that I want to use encrypted user name and password for mail setting.
My question is that how can I use any encrypted property with mail setting as well as any 
other attributes in Grails(i.e. Database user credentials....).

Regards,
Sanjay Kharwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already somewhat answered in the 2 following places:

[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336391/howto-encrypt-passwords-in-configuration-files-grails-and-java)

[Grails-3620](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3620)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this site while searching: http://grsage.com/new/GrailsPasswordEncyrption.html

It's pretty straight foward.